# Как получить самую ближайшую по дате запись?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby, activerecord

Есть таблица с записями. У записей есть поле `date_start` (тип `DATE`).
Хочу получить запись, чья дата максимально близка к `Time.zone.today`.

Первое, что приходит в голову - это изначально отсортировать их по `date_start`, а затем:

```
.order(date_start: :desc).where('date_start <= ?', Time.zone.today).first
```

Но этот способ работает не точно и порой выдает неверные результаты.

Comment: "близка" с одной стороны или с обеих? Какой запрос выдаёт описанная конструкция? Как выглядит якобы неверный результат?

Answer (score 0):

```
select sku.sku_id, sku.name, abs(date(now())-date(sku.created)) as diff 
from sku 
order by diff limit 1;
```

Получите запись таблицы sku с датой создания ближайшей от текущей.

Размер таблицы sku в моей базе - 88432 записи, время выполнения ~50 ms